# Calling a web server on my computer from a smartphone

Tags: apache, http

I have this strange problem that i haven't been able to figure out. Can anyone please suggest what to try:

I have a piece of software to control my camera from my computer. It's called "Control my Nikon". It has a built-in web server. The purpose is to be able to connect from a smartphone to use it as a remote control. You choose what port it should listen to and enable it. You get a simple interface with buttons. Exposing a photo, for example, triggers the URL 127.0.0.1:8090/?c=3. Very basic stuff.

On the computer it works perfectly, but from my phone, i just get a timeout. I figured i needed to open the port (8090) in my firewall and spent some time setting that up, but it still won't work. I am using my computer's IP address on the network: 192.168.1.214:8090, which should reach the same place as 127.0.0.1:8090 from the computer.

I then set up a Spring boot application to listen to the 8090 port and i was able to reach that from the phone just fine. This suggests that the firewall is not the issue. I can trigger the control my Nikon URL from within the Spring boot application too, by making a call to http://127.0.0.1:8090/?c=3. I can also reach pages served by Apache (192.168.1.214/testpage.html) on the computer from the phone without any problems.

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The Nikon software is probably binding itself to the `127.0.0.1` network interface and not *every* network interface it finds.

The software doesn't appear to be designed for network control but just runs a web server so it can present a UI in HTML.

You would need to change the Nikon software so it listens on other ports (or configure port forwarding or a reverse proxy).

Comment: I can choose what port i want it to listen to. I've tried different ones but the results are consistent.